# How to see environment variables from inside Flask based code

Tags: python, flask, environment-variables, virtualenv

I am working in Visual Studio 2022, Community Edition.
I am writing a Python based REST API using Flask.
I have created a virtual environment called "dupiqenv" (you will see evidence of it in the examples below). I used Visual Studio to create the environment. It is pathed under the project location "\dupiq\dupiqenv..."
I have an application that needs an APP key to connect to a service.
I am putting that in an environment variable called "OPENAI_APPKEY"

The following line is in my activate.ps1 file:

```
# set the app key
$env:OPENAI_APPKEY = "thisistheappkey"
```

I have confirmed this key is getting set from the developer powershell console:

```
(dupiqenv) PS C:\Users\wayne\source\repos\dupiqpy> $Env:OPENAI_APPKEY
thisistheappkey
```

Here is my code:

```
class EmbeddingProvider(object):
    """description of class"""
    
    def getEmbeddings(message):
        token = os.getenv('OPENAI_APPKEY')
        endpoint = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/embeddings'
        ...
```

When I run the web app and set a breakpoint on then the line "endpoint = ..." above, the value that is set for "token" is "None." I have examined the entire contents of the environment at this point, and "OPENAI_APPKEY" is not in there. In fact, none of the variables set in activate.ps1 are in there.

How do I make this work? Is there something I am missing in how the project is setup?

[image: Screenshot of app in breakpoint with environment variable resolving to nothing]

Comment: _When I run the web app..._ How exactly are you running the app?  From the command line?  From an IDE?  Show us the exact procedure.

Comment: in flask shell mode, check if you are able to access the key ornot

Comment: John Gordon: I am sorry, I do not really know what you mean by "flask shell mode". I have flask because it was available as the template I selected when I created the project in Visual Studio.

Comment: sahasrara: I am launching the app from the IDE, which is Visual Studio.

Comment: How exactly do you launch the IDE?  Do you launch it from a command prompt where the virtualenv was already activated?  Or do you launch it by double-clicking an icon on your desktop?

Comment: I type "Visual Studio" in the Windows command box, and the menu of apps appears. I select my solution (dupiqpy.sln) from the MRU list.

Comment: @WayneRoseberry It appears you are setting the env var in a PowerShell session but launching Visual Studio from the Windows GUI. Normal env vars are private to each process and normally only visible to programs launched by a PowerShell session. Windows (unlike Unix) does have a concept of "global" env vars but that isn't what you are using. You need to launch Visual Studio from a PowerShell session if you want it to see the env you set in PowerShell.

Comment: I have been told that if you use the developer powershell console in Visual Studio and set an environment variable there that it will be visible when you launch the app from within Visual Studio.

So... that is wrong, I guess.

Fine. I don't care. I just want to know how to set an environment variable that does NOT check into source code, is specific to this project, and is available from within the Python code.

Comment: @WayneRoseberry Env vars set in your *activate.ps1* file are not going to be visible to programs run by Visual Studio. At least given my limited understanding of how VS behaves.